# Are there more views akin to quad view?

Tags: 3d-view

I know of all the contextual views as seen here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html

What I am looking for are views that separate the 3Dview editor into different views as "quad view", but with different numbers than just 4. Something like a "bi view" or "tri view". Though I guess it would only be possible by multiples of 2 as "16 view" if it exists.

By the way, I know we can do something like that by splitting editors, and even make them of any size like this. But what I want is only one editor being equaly separated into multiple views.